# UIImageView get blurry if i draw on it after having zoomed in

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, quartz-graphics, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have an `UIImageView` displaying a picture.

I registered a pinch gesture to zoom in/out and a pan gesture to draw on it (I have a good reason to use the pan gesture for that, instead of touchMoved)

Here is the pinch target:

```
    - (void)pinchGestureActionOnSubject:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinch
    {

          if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinch state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
          {
                _lastScale = 1.0;
          }

          CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (_lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinch scale]);

          CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.imageViewSubject.transform;
          CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

          [self.imageViewSubject setTransform:newTransform];

          _lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinch scale];
    }
```

and here is the pan target:

```
    -(void) panOnSubjectForDrawing:(id)sender
    {

         if([sender numberOfTouches] > 0)
         { 

              CGPoint currentPoint = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.imageViewSubject];

              if(lastPoint.x == 0 || lastPoint.y == 0)
              {
                  lastPoint.x = currentPoint.x;
                  lastPoint.y = currentPoint.y;    
              }

              UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageViewSubject.bounds.size);

              CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

              [self.imageViewSubject.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageViewSubject.bounds.size.width, self.imageViewSubject.bounds.size.height)  blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

              CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

              CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10); // Epaisseur du trait

              CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear); // Transparent

              CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
              CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
              CGContextStrokePath(context);

              self.imageViewSubject.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

              UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
              lastPoint = currentPoint;

       }


   }
```

The problem is that if I draw after I zoom in, the picture get blurry. But if I draw without zoom, the image keep intact.

I heard that it can be because my frame has to be integer, so I add:

```
self.imageViewSubjectframe = CGRectIntegral(self.imageViewSubject.frame);
```

before I draw, but it is worst, more more more blurry.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. How did you finally fixed this issue?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue...i worked it around by using UIBezierPath instead of CGPath, and manipulated the image as a Background Image of a regular UIView, instead of manipulating the UIImageView itself. But i would rather be using this method you posted, since Bezier paths are slow.